# How to specify yaxs/xaxs='i' for axis() function?

Tags: r, plot, axis

I am trying to specify a 4th axis:

```
axis(side=4, at=seq(0,4,1), yaxs='i')
```

I want this axis to start and end at the very top and bottom of the graph, similar to how you would code this in the `plot()` function, with `yaxs='i'`. However, `yaxs='i'` in the `axis()` function does nothing. Is there anything similar to `yaxs='i'/xaxs='i'` in the `axis()` function?

Comment: you don't need to do that, I'm guessing you are wanting something like `plot(-10:10, yaxs = 'i', bty = 'n'); axis(4, at = 0:4); axis(4, lwd.ticks = 0)` but you should a reproducible example of what youre doing

Comment: `axis` does not have a yaxs or xaxs parameter because that would imply htat specifying a different version would need to change the range of the graphical area. That's not part of the base graphical model. Read about `x/yaxp`, `x/yaxs` and `x/yaxt` in `?par`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `par(new = TRUE)` to get your second axis; you can simply add `yaxs` to this call and the device to which you're plotting will obey:

```
par(new = TRUE, yaxs = 'i')
axis(side = 4, 0:4)
```

Even if you're not using `par(new = TRUE)`, simply call `par(yaxs = 'i')` just before running `axis()` should do the trick.